# Exporting "pattern matcher" but not "constructor"

Tags: haskell

If I have a module containing

```
data Foo = Bar Int | Baz Bool
```

can I export `Bar` and `Baz` in their role as "pattern matchers" or "destructors" *only* and not allow the module user to construct values of type `Foo` using them?

That is, I want to permit the usage

```
f (Bar i) = ... i ...
```

but prevent the usage

```
x = Bar i
```

Answer (score 5):

No. Pattern matches are defined in [terms of constructors](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17).  You either [export](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1000005.2) them and therefore enable users to pattern match *and* create new `Foo`s, or you don't.

If you just want to prevent a user to create some internal type, you could use an intermediate one:

```
module Foo (Foo, FooRep(..), toRep) where

data Foo    = Bar Int  | Baz Bool
data FooRep = BarR Int | BazR Bool

toRep (Bar i) = BarR i
toRep (Baz b) = BazR b
```

```
import Foo

f foo = case (toRep foo) of
           BarR i -> ... 
           BazR b -> ...
```

Comment: Actually, this is possible now in GHC 7.8 with unidirectional pattern synonyms: `data Foo = Bar' Int | Baz' Bool; pattern Bar n <- Bar' n; pattern Baz n <- Baz' n`. Then, you can just export those pattern synonyms. They will allow `example (Baz n) = ...` but not `example' = Baz ...`.

Comment: @DavidYoung: [Joachim already mentions this in the older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172548/is-it-possible-to-export-constructors-for-pattern-matching-but-not-for-construc). Still this question is about whether it's possible to export constructors as pattern-matchers only, so "No" as an answer holds, since you have something different than `Foo` or `Bar` at the end :).