# How can I simplify this pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, logic

Im trying to create a model of a propositional logic in Haskell, and i need a function to apply some logic rules to specific subexpressions. The function "apply" takes a list which indicate the position of the subexpression in the tree (in terms of right and left sequences), a logic rule and a logic expression and returns a new logic expression.

```
data LogicExp  a = P a                              | 
                     True'                      | 
                     False'                                 | 
                     Not' (LogicExp a)                  |  
                     (LogicExp a) :&  (LogicExp a)  | 
                     (LogicExp a) :|  (LogicExp a)  | 
                     (LogicExp a) :=> (LogicExp a)    |
                     (LogicExp a) :=  (LogicExp a)
    deriving Show


type LExp = LogicExp String

data Position = L | R

deMorgan :: LExp -> LExp
deMorgan (e1 :& e2) = Not' ((Not e1) :| (Not e2))
deMorgan (e1 :| e2) = Not' ((Not e1) :& (Not e2))
deMorgan x = x

apply :: [Position] -> (LExp -> LExp) -> LExp -> LExp
apply [] f e = f e
apply (L:xs) f (e1 :& e2) = (apply xs f e1) :& e2
apply (R:xs) f (e1 :& e2) = e1 :& (apply xs f e2)
apply (L:xs) f (e1 :| e2) = (apply xs f e1) :| e2
apply (R:xs) f (e1 :| e2) = e1 :| (apply xs f e2)
apply (L:xs) f (e1 :=> e2) = (apply xs f e1) :=> e2
apply (R:xs) f (e1 :=> e2) = e1 :=> (apply xs f e2)
apply (L:xs) f (e1 := e2) = (apply xs f e1) := e2
apply (R:xs) f (e1 := e2) = e1 := (apply xs f e2)
apply (x:xs) f (Not' e) = apply xs f e
```

The function works fine. But can I use some data constructor "wildcard" to have a more simple function like this?

```
apply :: [Position] -> (LExp -> LExp) -> LExp -> LExp
apply [] f e = f e
apply (L:xs) f (e1 ?? e2) = (apply xs f e1) ?? e2
apply (R:xs) f (e1 ?? e2) = e1 ?? (apply xs f e2)
apply (x:xs) f (Not' e) = apply xs f e
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment I can't recall any fancy tricks for doing that. One thing you might want to do, however, is factoring out the common structure in your `LogicExp` constructors:

```
data LogicExp a
    = P a
    | True'
    | False'
    | Not' (LogicExp a) 
    | Bin' BinaryOp (LogicExp a) (LogicExp a)
    deriving Show

data BinaryOp = And' | Or' | Impl' | Equiv'
    deriving Show
```

```
apply :: [Position] -> (LExp -> LExp) -> LExp -> LExp
apply [] f e = f e
apply (L:xs) f (Bin' op e1 e2) = Bin' op (apply xs f e1) e2
apply (R:xs) f (Bin' op e1 e2) = Bin' op e1 (apply xs f e2)
apply (x:xs) f (Not' e) = apply xs f e
-- ... and the P, True' and False' cases.
```

By doing that you lose the cute infix constructors. If you really want them back, however, there is a fancy trick: [view patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns) (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8172548/2751851) for more examples and discussion).

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic case for using one of the Generics packages, either [syb](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb) or [uniplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate).

Generally `uniplate` is faster but not as capable as `syb`. Fortunately in this case you can get away with using `uniplate`.

Steps to make use of `uniplate`:

1. use the `DeriveDataTypeable` pragma.
2. auto derive `Data` and `Typeable`
3. import `Data.Data` and a uniplate module like `Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data`

The transformation function you want is simply `transform` with the appropriate type signature:

```
doit :: LExp -> LExp
doit = transform deMorgan
```

where `deMorgan` is exactly as you have written it.

Complete example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module Lib6 where

import Data.Data
import Data.Generics.Uniplate.Data
import Text.Show.Pretty (ppShow)

data LogicExp  a = P a                              |
                     True'                      |
                     False'                                 |
                     Not' (LogicExp a)                  |
                     (LogicExp a) :&  (LogicExp a)  |
                     (LogicExp a) :|  (LogicExp a)  |
                     (LogicExp a) :=> (LogicExp a)    |
                     (LogicExp a) :=  (LogicExp a)
    deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

type LExp = LogicExp String

data Position = L | R

deMorgan :: LExp -> LExp
deMorgan (e1 :& e2) = Not' ((Not' e1) :| (Not' e2))
deMorgan (e1 :| e2) = Not' ((Not' e1) :& (Not' e2))
deMorgan x = x

doit :: LExp -> LExp
doit = transform deMorgan

example = (P "a" :& P "b") :| (P "c")

test = putStrLn $ ppShow (doit example)
```

Running `test` produces:

```
Not' (Not' (Not' (Not' (P "a") :| Not' (P "b"))) :& Not' (P "c"))
```

An intro tutorial on uniplate:

http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/uniplate/uniplate.htm