# Hide a constructor but not the type on import

Tags: haskell, module

I've got an internal module I'd like to provide an external API for

```
module Positive.Internal where

newtype Positive a = Positive { getPositive :: a }
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

-- smart constructor
toPositive :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe (Positive a)
toPositive a | a <= 0    = Nothing
             | otherwise = Just $ Positive a
-- ...
```

I want to hide the dumb constructor, and replace it with a unidirectional
pattern so users can still pattern match values, they just have to use the smart constructor to use new values.

Since I want the pattern and the dumb constructor to use the same name, I need to hide the dumb constructor to prevent namespace clashes.

However, since the dumb constructor and the type share names, it's a little tricky to import the everything BUT the dumb constructor.

Currently I'm doing this, which works ok:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
module Positive
  ( module Positive.Internal, pattern Positive
  ) where

import Positive.Internal (Positive())
import Positive.Internal hiding (Positive)
import qualified Positive.Internal as Internal

pattern Positive :: a -> Positive a
pattern Positive a <- Internal.Positive a
```

I could simplify my imports by just using the qualified import, but I'm curious.

Is there a way to, in a single import statement, import all of `Positive.Internal` except the dumb constructor?

I tried `hiding (Positive(Positive))`, but that hid both the type and the dumb constructor. I've poked about [the wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import), but I haven't noticed any way to differentiate between constructors and types in `hiding` lists.

Comment: I take it hiding the `newtype`'s constructor inside the internal module isn't an option? If it is, you could rename the `newtype` constructor to (say) `Positive_`, move the `Positive` pattern synonym to the internal module and export that instead.

Comment: I think the question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172548/is-it-possible-to-export-constructors-for-pattern-matching-but-not-for-construc Nothing changed since then. This GHC trac ticket suggests to not create new pattern synonym but just use `pattern` on current constructor: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8753 But unfortunately this will also export constructor, not only pattern :( Because constructor pattern by default is bidirectional.

Comment: Why do you want the pattern and dumb constructor to have the same name?  Why not just name the dumb constructor something else? Your uses don't get to see it anyway.  Or am I misunderstanding...

Comment: When you're trying to define a name in a module which is the same as a name in an imported module, you're probably much better off using `import qualified` and qualified references, rather than trying to set up really finicky imports to get the implicit unqualified namespace to have exactly what you want in it.

Comment: @luqui b/c it makes refactoring from using the internal API to the external API really easy.  Change the import statement, and then, as long as I'm not using the dumb constructor, I'm all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I am almost certain this is what you are looking for:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
module Positive
  ( module Positive.Internal, pattern Positive, foo
  ) where

import Positive.Internal hiding (pattern Positive)
import qualified Positive.Internal as Internal (pattern Positive)

pattern Positive :: a -> Positive a
pattern Positive a <- Internal.Positive a

foo :: Positive Int
foo = Internal.Positive 5
```

`Internal` module stays the same way as it is defined so far. And for the sake of example:

```
module Negative where

import Positive

bar :: Maybe Int
bar = getPositive <$> toPositive 6
```

Let's double check in GHCi:

```
Prelude> :load Negative
[1 of 3] Compiling Positive.Internal ( Positive/Internal.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 3] Compiling Positive         ( Positive.hs, interpreted )
[3 of 3] Compiling Negative         ( Negative.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Negative, Positive, Positive.Internal.
*Negative> bar
Just 6
*Negative> getPositive foo
5
*Negative> :i Positive
newtype Positive a = Positive.Internal.Positive {getPositive :: a}
    -- Defined at Positive/Internal.hs:3:1
instance [safe] Ord a => Ord (Positive a)
  -- Defined at Positive/Internal.hs:4:17
instance [safe] Eq a => Eq (Positive a)
  -- Defined at Positive/Internal.hs:4:13
*Negative> :t Positive

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • non-bidirectional pattern synonym ‘Positive’ used in an expression
    • In the expression: Positive
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know that you could specify constructors using the `pattern` keyword. Thanks so much.